# I want To generate all category button

Tags: vb.net

I have this pos system i want to generate All category button and display All product list in the FlowLayoutPanel
[image]

```
Private Sub FrmPos_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Connection()
    LoadCategory()
    LoadMenu()
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub
```

this code for  LoadCategory()

```
 Sub LoadCategory()
        cn.Open()
        cm = New SqlCommand("Select * From TblCategory", cn)
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            BtnCategory = New Button
            BtnCategory.Width = 100
            BtnCategory.Height = 35
            BtnCategory.Text = dr.Item("Category").ToString
            BtnCategory.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
            BtnCategory.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(55, 176, 213)
            BtnCategory.ForeColor = Color.White
            BtnCategory.Cursor = Cursors.Hand
            BtnCategory.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft

            FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(BtnCategory)

            AddHandler BtnCategory.Click, AddressOf filter_click

        End While

        dr.Close()
        cn.Close()

    End Sub
```

this code for filter_click

```
Public Sub filter_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If LblTransNo.Text = String.Empty Then
        MsgBox("Click New Order first!", vbCritical)
        Return

    End If


    _filter = sender.text.ToString
    LoadMenu()
End Sub
```

Comment: ...and what is, or is not, working?!

Comment: i want to add All button to load all Categories @Idle_Mind

Comment: Gotcha, you want a button at the top for "All"?  Create it just like the other ones, but BEFORE the loop. Can you show the code in `filter_click()`?

Comment: @Idle_Mind i edit the code you can check filter_click() sub code

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different things going on in the `LoadCategory` method. I moved the database code to a separate method.

Connections, Commands, and DataReaders all need to be disposed. These objects need to be declared locally in `Using` blocks. They provide a `Dispose` method where they release unmanaged resources. `Using...End Using` blocks will call `Dispose` for you and close the object even if there is an error.

You don't want to hold a connection open while you build your buttons and interact with the user interface. It appears that you are only using a single field called Category. Don't pull down all the fields with `Select *`. Just return the data you need to use.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LoadFlowPanel()
    LoadMenu()
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub
Private OPConStr As String = "Your connection string."
Private Function GetCategoryData() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Category From TblCategory;", cn)
        cn.Open()
        Using dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(dr)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub LoadFlowPanel()
    Dim dt = GetCategoryData()
    Dim BtnAll As New Button
    With BtnAll
        .Width = 100
        .Height = 35
        .Text = "All"
        .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
        .BackColor = Color.FromArgb(55, 176, 213)
        .ForeColor = Color.White
        .Cursor = Cursors.Hand
        .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
    End With
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(BtnAll)
    AddHandler BtnAll.Click, AddressOf filter_click

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim BtnCategory = New Button
        With BtnCategory
            .Width = 100
            .Height = 35
            .Text = row("Category").ToString
            .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
            .BackColor = Color.FromArgb(55, 176, 213)
            .ForeColor = Color.White
            .Cursor = Cursors.Hand
            .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
        End With
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(BtnCategory)
        AddHandler BtnCategory.Click, AddressOf filter_click
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: i try your code but when i click on All button i get no data for products

Comment: I put the filter_click code

Comment: Ask a new question and show the code in the click event.